# What kind of sand and gravel for artificial grass

Tags: landscaping

I'm trying to buy some gravel and sand for the base and infill of artificial grass but am confused by the variety and types of sand and gravel.

Is just a general-purpose sand and gravel bag from Sacrete good enough?

Answer (score 0):

At the quantity you will need I would be purchasing yards of sand (beach sand) for extra smooth or river sand for a bit corse but probably cheaper and acceptable alternative buying in bags is crazy expensive unless you only need a dozen bags.
In my area there are places you can get free beach sand but I am close to the coast.

Comment: Never use beach sand for construction, unless you want salt contaminating your concrete, site, etc. We only use beach sand for volleyball courts, etc. because it “fluffs up”. You need sand that will compact like crushed rock/sand and river sand. https://nearsay.com/c/530930/227030/5-types-of-sand-used-in-construction

Comment: It's funny, they actually import sand to our beach sculpting competitions, because sea beach sand around here doesn't hold shape well.

Comment: Lee it is not construction it is for under Astro turf

Comment: Whatever type of sand and gravel you use, buying it by the truckload and having a dump truck drop it off for you will very likely be much cheaper and a _ton_ (intended) easier.

Comment: @EdBeal As I said, “You’ll contaminate your concrete AND site.” Just as David said, it doesn’t hold shape...the lawn will “move” because it doesn’t compact. (Are you the one who says all concrete cracks or will crack? Maybe it’s because you’re using beach sand under and in your concrete.)

Comment: I have put beach sand down and covered it with a tarp on asphalt it held up just fine. , I do not use beach sand with concrete. There is not enough to bother the lawn or any of my plants either my grandsons sand box and the area around it is beach sand.